# Do I need to Create New Branch in Git if I am must rolling back changes?

Tags: tortoisegit

I Commited  (call it Original).  Then I made a bunch of changes.
Now I want to just roll them all back.

So I'm doing a Switch/Checkout. But I'm wondering **if (and why) I need to Create New Branch (the default option).**

[image]

Comment: Please consider to upvote or commenting so that we can see whether our answers are right or we can provide more information. We spend our time helping you and get no feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First: Dropping commits means that you want to change the history. This might be problematic if you work with other people on a common repository and you already pushed your changes. - Either you do this rollback as described in the following text and force push (then you collaborators need to adjust their local history manually after pulling) or you revert the commits (option `revert change by this commit`) and push these changes (the revert is a normal commit which reverts the changes and will be automatically applied to your collaborators on pull).

If you really want to roll back all changes, the fastest way to go is to perform a "hard reset" to the revision you want to go back to (then the history and all files in the working tree are rolled back to the state of that revision, the other commits will be discarded as if those never happened).

If you want to keep one or more commits in the history, you should go for a rebase operation. Select the commit in the log dialog which should be the base for the "new" history and select "rebase onto this revision". Then flag all commits you want to drop as skip and perform the rebase.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html#tgit-dug-showlog-actions and https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html

(Your itend to performa a "Switch" sounds like you have a SVN background; switch/checkout in Git means in generall that you want to switch to an existing branch or create a new branch).

Answer (score 0):

see the [documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html#tgit-dug-showlog-actions) ...in that GUI it's called `revert change by this commit`:

> Revert changes from which were made in the selected revision. All changes are integrated into your working tree. You may choose to commit immediately or edit and commit later. To abandon the reverted changes, perform a hard reset.